# Guide for Quantum Information and Computing Internships and Learning Opportunities

Tags: resource-request

I know this perhaps not a suitable topic for this SE - after all, this is about QC knowledge sharing - but **I am wondering if this could be a resource for people who are interested in the field, are currently enrolled in college - undergrad and beyond** - and would like to know the best way - **for their current station in the physics/QC track/journey** - to approach/pursue the many opportunities there are out there.

I really hope the community takes upon this question and this becomes a wiki for people to come and see the feedback from the community to be better prepared to compete for those learning opportunity - specially the internships, which as far as I know, are not that many.

Answer (score 1):

1. Play "Hello Quantum" it is a game by IBM on App Store and
   iTunes
2. Sign up for IBM Q / Quantum Experience -
   https://www.ibm.com/quantum-computing/technology/experience - when
   you are there bookmark http://qiskit.org and
   https://qiskit.org/textbook/preface.html
3. Look for Blogs  especially Microsoft's and Jonathan Hui's blogs - they are fantastic!
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum

   https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/qc-quantum-computing-series-10ddd7977abd
4. Eventually make it a habit to look at papers in what interests you at arxiv.org if 
   Finance is what interests you - start with this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03890